# How to embed MS-access form in C# windows application project?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, ms-access

I have created a MS-access data base. In this database I created some tables and some forms. Now I know how to add ms-access database in my C# application. But I want to import all form in C# windows application project which were created in MS-access database. Is it possible? If YES,, How? please help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: help please. I need it badly

Comment: does the information on this question help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953577/how-to-embed-ms-access-forms-in-c-sharp-module ?

Comment: No, I have already seen this.

Comment: then i suppose you looking for something beyond just calling access from C#, and you want the actual access forms in your C# app.  No, that is not possible.

Comment: or, can I write C# code on the button of ms-access form?